# HTML5 chrome browser datalist scrollbar missing

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-datalist

Chrome browser does not seem to have a scrollbar for datalist.  It works on firefox and IE, but not chrome.  Is this a chrome issue with not keeping up with HTML5 standards?  Can I manually add it with CSS?

Comment: There's an [open bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375637) for this. please **star** it so it will get higher priority

Answer (score 2):

It’s not much of answer, I know, but from what I’ve read/tried you don’t have any control over how it’s displayed.

I know it’s not really a solution, but you could try using a jQuery plugin that has pretty much the same functionality, but allows for better styling. Untested, but [QuickSelect](http://edelholz.net/js/jquery/quickselect/sample.html) looks it’ll do the same, or you could look for a polyfill.